# Convert text date to datetime SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to select and insert the info from table1 database1 and insert it into table1 database2. The problem is that these records have a varchar date (12 december 2012) I want to convert that date to datetime, and then insert it into another table of the database2. How can I do that?

I'm doing a test with this code:

```
DECLARE @date nvarchar(30)
SET @date = '12 of enero of 2012'

PRINT @date
PRINT cast((REPLACE('12 of enero of 2012', 'of', '')as datetime)
```

Comment: don't forget to mark the correct answer for future reference

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cast it, like so

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('12 of december of 2011', 'of ', '') AS DATETIME)
```

so all you have to do for insert is,

```
-- In your last update I noticed you are using Spanish
-- So you'll have to put <b>SET LANGUAGE SPANISH</b> before your query
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (MyDateTimeField)
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(MyVarCharThatContainsDateTimeField, 'of ', '') AS DATETIME)
FROM TABLE2
```

Notice that this will throw an error if your string is not a date:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: Ok, and what if these dates have the next format...12 of december of 2011, also I have to do this convert on all records of this table

Comment: not gonna work with the 'of', you can still do this: CAST(REPLACE('12 of december of 2011', 'of', '') AS DATETIME)

Answer (score 0):

The CONVERT function works to convert this date format.

```
convert(datetime, '12 december 2012')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your test code (and other answers):

```
SET LANGUAGE Spanish

DECLARE @date nvarchar(30)
SET @date = '12 of enero of 2012'

PRINT @date
PRINT cast(REPLACE(@date, 'of', '') as datetime)
```